# PHP Mysql Results to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have one array and would like to add some static value into array and get the expected result in JSON.

Original Array:

```
$results=
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'country' => 'SG ',
    'id' => '1 ',
    'name' => 'jerome ',
    'course1' => 'IT ',
    'course2' => 'Music ',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'country' => 'US ',
    'id' => '2 ',
    'name' => 'cindy ',
    'course1' => 'IT ',
    'course2' => 'Music ',
  ),
);
```

Expected JSON Result:

```
{
  "SG":{
  "name":"jerome",
  "id":"1",
  "Course":[
     {
        "hall1":"IT"
     },
     {
        "hall2":"Music"
     }
  ]
},
  "US":{
  "name":"cindy",
  "id":"2",
  "Course":[
     {
        "hall1":"IT"
     },
     {
        "hall2":"Music"

     }
  ]
 }
}
```

I tried to use this to echo array into json but failed to get the expected result

```
foreach ($results as $result){
    $data[]=array(
      $result['country']=>array(
        "name"=>$result['name'],
        "id"=>$result['id'],
        "Course"=>array(
        "hall1"=>$result['course1'],
        "hall2"=>$result['course2']
        )
      )
    );
  }
echo json_encode($data);
```

Result:

```
[
 {
  "SG":{
     "name":"jerome",
     "id":"1",
     "Course":{
        "hall1":"IT",
        "hall2":"Music"
     }
  }
 },
 {
  "US":{
     "name":"cindy",
     "id":"2",
     "Course":{
        "hall1":"IT",
        "hall2":"Music"
     }
  }
 }
]
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script (i couldnt comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i made few changes to your current code to make it work as expected.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/820110)

```
foreach ($results as $result){
    $data[$result['country']]=//added country as index.
      array(
        "name"=>$result['name'],
        "id"=>$result['id'],
        "Course"=>array(
        array("hall1"=>$result['course1']),//surrounded it by array
        array("hall2"=>$result['course2'])//surrounded it by array
        )
     );
 }
echo json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: i hope you wrapped the expected output in an array for easy data retrieval, because his expected json result above didn't seem to have that. @Sahil Gulati

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Make a array inside the array

```
"Course"=>array(
        array("hall1"=>$result['course1']),
        array("hall2"=>$result['course2']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following snippet is just updated version of your code, the response which you want can be achieved by encoding JSON like this 
`json_encode($data,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`

but it will make JSON Object only so your `Course` Array will also become JSON OBJECT

```
    foreach ($results as $result){
    $arr[$result['country']] = [
        'name' => $result['name'],
        'id' => $result['id'],
        'Course' => [
            ['hall1' => $result['course1']],
            ['hall2' => $result['course2']]
        ]
    ];

    $data[] = $arr;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```